# How to rotate iOS app only on iPhone 6+

Tags: iphone, xcode, storyboard, ios8, autolayout

My application is on iPhone in portratit mode. I have also iPad version, that can rotate. Now, with new iPhone 6+, I would like to rotate my app. I have found any problems / solutions regarding this issue.

There are two ways that I can think of

a) better solution (imho) - enable rotation only for certain device. Can it be done without editing code somewhere in project setting ?

b) use iPad version of storyboard on iPhone6+ instead of classic iPhone version of storybaod. Can it be done from within XCode storyboard or project settings, or do I have to do this in my code? I have found no other solution, that to load certain storyboard in code based on device identification.

Comment: In the iPad storyboard how do you handle portrait/landscape orientation?

Comment: @sha I check it in app settings in XCode to enable portrait / landscape. But this can be done only for iPhone / iPad, no device type specifier is present. Otherwise, In storyboard I am using constraints and auto-layout

Answer (score 3):

Here's an easy way to accomplish this. Just add the following to your `UIApplicationDelegate`:

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
    static UIInterfaceOrientationMask rv = 0;
    if( rv == 0 ) {
        if( [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone ) {
            CGSize s = window.bounds.size;
            if( MAX( s.width, s.height ) >= 700.0f ) {
                rv = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
            } else {
                rv = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
            }
        } else {
            rv = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
        }
    }
    return rv;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Apple recommended approach is to combine both iPhone and iPad storyboards into one and use Size Classes in that storyboards to change constraints based on the device/orientation.

As for enabling rotation in particular device - again you might check size classes inside your view controller or check for specific devices resolution. I don't think there is way to enable/disable it for device classes (iPhone 6 vs iPhone 6+) in the project settings.

Comment: I was afraid of that. My app is older, so I have separate storyboard for iPhone and iPad and they are different (elements positions, effects etc.)

Comment: If you're planning to support your app going forward I'd recommend to deal with storyboards now. You can control position/size of elements based on devices classes pretty easy in this combined storyboard.